# Storing items of an array depending on another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array called catalogue which holds 4 items:

packageid, dataid , categoryid and datapackage.

What I want to do is push into the array **dataids** all the dataids of items whose `packageid` is equal to `packageBtnFilter` and whose `categoryid` is equal to `categoryBtnFilter`. If the value of `packageBtnFilter` and `categoryBtnFilter` are both 0 then it should push all the dataids of catalogue into the `dataids` array. At the moment it just pushes the dataids of items whose packageid is equal to 3.

```
              var packageBtnFilter = $('#packages').val();
              var categoryBtnFilter = $('#categories').val();   

                var dataids = new Array();

                $(catalogue).each(function () {
                  if (this.packageid == 3) dataids.push(this.dataid);
                });
```

Thanks!
the full code is here 
http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/Tcwgf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter the result and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the ids:

```
var dataids = (
   categoryBtnFilter==0 && packageBtnFilter==0
   ? catalogue
   : catalogue.filter(function(i) {
       return i.categoryid=categoryBtnFilter && i.packageid==packageBtnFilter
   })
).map(function(i){return i.dataid});
```

Comment: I think you forgot the 0-condition; nevermind, you corrected :)

Comment: @alexb no, read my answer again. I simply think it's much better to not test it in the loop, both for readability and for performances.

Comment: I fully agree with you, in your initial post I didn't see the comment about the 0-condition but I think I missed it, mea culpa

Comment: thanks, but how do I add the condition if they are both equal to 0? then we should return all.

Comment: thanks very much, the only thing is, it should only return the dataids into the variable dataids, at the moment you return all the value of each item, can you edit that please?

Comment: he needs something like $.map + $.grep rather than $.filter. I know that $.filter is used mostly for DOM elements

Comment: @alexb Yes, I had overlooked this point. Edited to return just the id.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your condition should be something like

```
if ((packageBtnFilter == 0 && categoryBtnFilter == 0) || this.packageid == packageBtnFilter || this.packageid == categoryBtnFilter) dataids.push(this.dataid);
```