# Pushing to an array from conditional statement

Tags: jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing items of an array depending on another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358151/storing-items-of-an-array-depending-on-another-value)

I have an array called catalogue which holds 4 items:

packageid, dataid , categoryid and datapackage.

What I want to do is push into the array result all the dataids of items whose packageid is equal to packageBtnFilter and whose categoryid is equal to categoryBtnFilter. If the value of packageBtnFilter and categoryBtnFilter are both 0 then it should push all the dataids of catalogue into the result array.

This is what I have so far:

```
var result = new Array();

var packageBtnFilter = $('#packages').val() ;
var categoryBtnFilter = $('#categories').val() ;

var test = $(catalogue).each(function () {
            if ( (packageBtnFilter!= 0)  && (categoryBtnFilter==0 ) ){
                return  this.packageid == packageBtnFilter;
            } else if ( (categoryBtnFilter!=0 )  &&   (packageBtnFilter!= 0)  ) {
                return this.categoryid == categoryBtnFilter;
            } else if ( (categoryBtnFilter==0 )  &&   (packageBtnFilter== 0)   ) {
                return
            } else {
                return this.packageid == packageBtnFilter  &&  this.categoryid == categoryBtnFilter;
                    }


             });
```

Comment: You even cut-and-paste from your original question; of course it is. All you did was edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a non-jQuery collection or HTML elements, you have to use `$.each` instead, as in:

```
$.each(catalogue, function () {
```

Additionally, `.each` just iterates and doesn't actually return anything.  Your returns are pretty much just noops.  Instead, you should push to `result` in the conditionals.

Comment: thanks any chance of explaining how to do so?

Comment: @user1937021 `result.push(this.datapackage)` I think .. just look up the JavaScript Array `push` method.